# Casting derived to base, and then casting that into another derived. Java

Tags: java, casting, downcast

So I have 3 classes.

`base`

`derived1` derived from `base`

`derived2` derived from `base`

This code says that derived1 cannot be casted to derived2, even though I already casted derived1 to a base object?

`base temp = (derived2)((base)derived1);`

I'm trying to cast derived1 into a derived2 object. And this was the only solution I could come up, is this valid? And is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: **Why** do you want to do that? **What** problem are you trying to solve? And, **how** does this help you solve it?

Comment: Experimenting with dynamic binding, and I wanted to call a function twice, once from derived1, and once from derived2 without creating two separate objects. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Even if it compiled it certainly wouldn't do what you expect it to do. Casting doesn't convert anything.

Comment: You will certainly end up with nothing more than a `ClassCastException`. Why not make proper use of interfaces to represent common functionality instead?

Comment: If I casted it, wouldn't it allow me to call a function from derived2, even if the current object is an instance of derived1? For example `derived1->display()` would call the display function that was implemented in the derived1 class, but using the code above, `temp->display()` would call the function implemented within the derived2 class.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the only means of dynamic binding in Java is via reflection. Start at [`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and go from there, you will probably find what you need. Note that there is almost always a better way (in particular, the caveat of reflection is you do not have the benefits of compile-time type checking).

Comment: No. It would still call the derived1 display. Why would it do otherwise?

Comment: @SieuPhan No it would not. Now, if `display()` was a method in `base`, then you could certainly cast both derived classes to a `base` and call it that way.

Comment: @SieuPhan No it won't, because the actual object actually isn't of that type, and Java won't let you lie about that.

Comment: Oh okay, that cleared it up, I just wanted to know if it was possible. Because I didn't get any errors in Eclipse, and it didn't do what was expected. I just might take the alternernative, and create two base objects and create an instance of `derived1` for one, and `derived2` for the other. That will probably be the better option for achieving what I'm looking for. Thanks guys/gals!@EJP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. You will certainly end up with nothing more than a `ClassCastException`.

If your method is a non-final method of `base` (possibly overridden in subclasses) then you can cast both to a `base` and call it that way.

You can also make proper use of interfaces to represent common functionality instead.

The only means of dynamic binding that Java offers is via reflection ([tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), also [`java.lang.Class` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)), e.g.:

```
myObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("display").invoke(myObject);
```

Bear in mind that you lose all benefits of compile-time type checking when using reflection (and also the interface is much more cumbersome) -- there is almost *always* a better way to accomplish the task without it (in your case, I have a hunch that there is most definitely a better way).

Answer (score 2):

In general, the code indicates the design problem. Ensure `derived1` and `derived2` '**is-a**' `base`, please.

How does a banana cast to an orange?

Comment: I was trying to cast a banana into a fruit, and cast the fruit into an orange! But I'll create two objects of fruit, and create an instance of banana, and the other an orange now.

Comment: @SieuPhan You are confusing "cast" with "convert". Correct: A banana **is a** fruit. Incorrect: A fruit **is an** orange. Incorrect: A banana **is an** orange. You could attempt `(Orange)myFruit` but if it isn't actually an orange then a `ClassCastException` will result at run time (not at compile time, which is why Eclipse wouldn't complain about it -- besides, think about it: There's no possible way to know that a given fruit was an orange at compile-time; conversely the compiler knows that a given orange is always a fruit).

Comment: Ahhhh @JasonC, I see where I went wrong, now that you put it that way, thanks!